# Not only the intersection of multiple sets, but also union and update

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the intersection between two `sets` in python. However, once found, I need to `union` the two sets and iterate again on the `dictionary` until no further change.

something like this:

```
dict_={'a': {1,3,4}, 'b': {0,5,4}, 'c': {0,6,5},'e':{7,9}}
```

What i need:

```
result={'abc':{1,3,4,0,5,4,0,6,5}, 'e':{7,9}}
```

here is What i did so far :

```
dict_={'a': {1,3,4}, 'b': {0,5,4}, 'c': {0,6,5},'e':{7,9}}    
flag=True
while flag:
    done=False
    for key in list(dict_):
        if done:        ## to break outer loop
            del dict_[remove1]
            del dict_[remove2]
            break
        for newKey in list(dict_):
            if key==newKey:
                continue
            if len(set.intersection(dict_[key],dict_[newKey]))>0:
                added_key=str(key)+str(newKey)
                dict_[added_key]=set.union(dict_[key],dict_[newKey])
                remove1=key
                remove2=newKey
                done=True
                break    ## to break inner loop
    flag=False     ## Here is the problem. I do not know what to do
```

Result of this code:

```
dict_
#{'ab': {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, 'c': {0, 5, 6}, 'e': {7, 9}}
```

Comment: Your desired answer:
`result={'abc':{1,3,4,0,5,4,0,6,5}, 'e':{7,9}}`
is not possible as `{1,3,4,0,5,4,0,6,5}` is not a valid set.

Comment: Also the order of the original key names in the aggregated ones might differ.

Comment: I guess it is valid. once I union 'a' and 'b' because they intersect in 4 then 'c' will intersect with the new set  'ab' because of 5.

Comment: It's not valid because a set cannot have duplicate elements.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I meant this {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}. the idea is that once I union 'a' and 'b' because they intersect in 4 then 'c' will intersect with the new set  'ab' because of 5.

Comment: thats what i want. will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out in comments, your desired output has an invalid set. Assuming you want to join the keys and union the value sets till they have anything in common, you could do like this:

```
d ={'a': {1,3,4}, 'b': {0,5,4}, 'c': {0,6,5},'e':{7,9}}

flag = True

while (flag):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    outer_break = False
    for i in range(len(keys)-1):
        inner_break = False
        for j in range(i+1, len(keys)):
            if len(set.intersection(d[keys[i]], d[keys[j]])) > 0:
                d[keys[i] + keys[j]] = set.union(d[keys[i]], d[keys[j]])
                del d[keys[i]]
                del d[keys[j]]
                inner_break = True
                break
        if inner_break:
            outer_break = True
            break
    if not outer_break:
        flag = False

print (d)
# {'e': {9, 7}, 'cab': {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
```

You could also do this with a recursive function like this:

```
dd ={'a': {1,3,4}, 'b': {0,5,4}, 'c': {0,6,5},'e':{7,9}}

def reduce_dict(d):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for i in range(len(keys)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(keys)):
            if len(set.intersection(d[keys[i]], d[keys[j]])) > 0:
                d[keys[i] + keys[j]] = set.union(d[keys[i]], d[keys[j]])
                del d[keys[i]]
                del d[keys[j]]
                return reduce_dict(d)
    return d

dd = reduce_dict(dd)

print(dd)
# {'e': {9, 7}, 'cab': {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to look at all possible unique key combinations, you can avoid using so many flags and instead use a seen set()  this way:

```
from itertools import combinations

dict_={'a': {1,3,4}, 'b': {0,5,4}, 'c': {0,6,5},'e':{7,9}}

for i in range(2,len(dict_)+1): # For length of dict from 2
    # Initialize the "seen" list
    seen_keys = set()
    for combination in list(combinations(dict_, 2)): # Get possible key combinations of 2
            keys_in_combination = [dict_[x] for x in combination] # And their values in a list

            if len(set.intersection(*keys_in_combination)): # * Expands the list into the arguments
                # Make key names alphabetical with no duplicate letters.
                added_key = "".join(sorted(set(x for y in combination for x in str(y))))
                # Join 2 sets under new key
                dict_[added_key] = set.union(*keys_in_combination)
                for seen_key in combination:
                    # create a seen list (for the deletion below)
                    seen_keys.add(seen_key)

    # Delete the keys which have been joined to others
    for key in dict_.copy():
        if len(key) < i and key in seen_keys:
            del dict_[key]

print(dict_)
```

Result:

```
{'abc': set([0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 'e': set([9, 7])}
```

This method will also work on dicts where combinations may be longer than "abc".

Answer (score 0):

One very optimized approach is to use a list of dictioanry items
and loop over the list then update the items recursively if they
have any intersection.

```
def find_intersection(m_list):
    for i, (key_1, v) in enumerate(m_list) : 
        for j, (key_2, k) in enumerate(m_list[i+1:],i+1):
        if v & k:
            m_list[i] = key_1 + key_2, v.union(m_list.pop(j)[1])
            return find_intersection(m_list)
    return m_list
```

Demo:

```
In [10]: find_intersection(list(mydict.items()))
Out[10]: [('abc', {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}), ('e', {7, 9})]
```